# Android: Get NullPointerException at SharedPreference.Editor after closing PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, editor, sharedpreferences

I have a PreferenceActivity used to changed preferences by the user. I also defined some preferences persisting some data that will not be displayed on the interface and I would like to change the data programmatically.

Here is the PreferenceActivity:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment()).commit();
}

public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements
        OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences_settings);
        getActivity().setTitle(R.string.title_settings);
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
                .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Here is the MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ...
    public void onDestroy() {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        //throws NullPointerException if SettingsActivity was created
        preferences.edit().putInt("Number", 0).commit();

        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

The strange thing is that if I opened the SettingsActivity, when MainActivity is onDestroy(), preferences.edit() throws a NullPointerException. If SettingsActivity was never created, preferences.edit() works fine.

It looks like the SettingsActivity prevents other activity from accessing SharedPreference.Editor. Could anyone please help me solve this?

Comment: Please post your exception call stack.

Comment: Super.onDestroy() must be the first call in the onDestroy() method.Isnt so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are forgetting to call `unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` when the SettingsFragment and SettingsActivity are destroyed. Hence attempting to edit the preferences when the application is shutting down is triggering a callback into your activity\fragment.

This is just a guess because your callback is for the SharedPreferences and the onDestroy code is for the DefaultSharedPreferences.

Comment: You are right, I need to call unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() at onPause(). Thanks a lot!

Comment: cool. If you put the unregister call in onPause, then the register call should be in onResume.  Otherwise, when you come back from pausing (such as returning from a preference list selector), you will lose your registration. I would recommend just keeping what you got in onCreate and putting the unregister in onDestroy.  But you know your code and activity/stack better than I do.

Comment: Exactly, I did not realize that. Thank you for your follow up!